# Three-phase power and consumption: what would the bill be?

Tags: power, mains, three-phase

Here's a theoretical question:

I have a three-phase power connection in home.

I connect three devices of 1000W (1 kW) each, one to each phase.

I then start them at the same time, for 1 hour.

What will my power bill be in this case?

More specifically, would it be 3 kW/h (as it would be in the case of one-phase setup), or would it somehow be *less* than that (because of three-phase power)?

Comment: Electricity metering is done either by watt-meters, in which case you’d pay for the 3kWh that you’ve used, or by VA meters that take account of power factor, in which case you’d pay for a minimum of 3kVAh if you power factor was a perfect 1.0

Comment: If it was less than that, we'd all be doing it.

Comment: @Frog what do _most_ people have at homes? you're saying that it's 3Kw/h _or maybe more_ but no less?

Comment: @MaratC Please note that it's `kW`, not `Kw`, and that `kW/h` is a nonsensical unit in this context (it means 3.6MJ per second per second); you mean `kWh` (3.6MJ). When discussing these things, and trying to understand them, it helps to get the units correct.

Comment: Domestic users typically have watt meters and are trusted to have a reasonable power factor overall.  Industrial 3-phase users may have VA meters which take into account loads with a low power factor, allowing the electricity supplier to compensate for the increased transmission losses.

Answer (score 1):

Each device will consume 1 kW for one hour which is an energy consumpution of 1 kW **×** 1h = 1 **kWh**, and **not** 1 kW/h.

With three heaters consumption will be 3 kWh.

> What will my power bill be in this case?

3 kWh or 3 "units".

> More specifically, would it be 3 kW/h ...

No, 3 **kWh**.

> ... or would it somehow be less than that (because of three-phase power)?

No, you are burning 3 kW for one hour so the energy you pay for is 3 kWh.

Answer (score 0):

> *What will my power bill be in this case?*

Each load consumes 1 kW whether they are all connected in parallel to a single phase or connected separately to the three individual phases. This of course makes the assumption that your utility meter is operating correctly and is being read correctly by the utility.

> *would it be 3 kW/h*

It would be power multiplied by time or kWh.